# I have the only one error to launch my magento project please help me

Tags: error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on boolean in /Users/LKM/MyMagentoProject/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php on line 71
```

above is what I got when accessing 'localhost'

I searched a lot and finally and actually came back to this same point.

the code the error message points is below :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $namespace = 'customer';
    if ($this->getCustomerConfigShare()->isWebsiteScope()) {
        $namespace .= '_' . (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode());
    }

    $this->init($namespace);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_session_init', array('customer_session'=>$this));
}
```

and this code is the line on 71 below :

```
    $namespace .= '_' . (Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsite()->getCode());
```

What could I do to solve this?

I think it's not about virtual host configuration, isn't it?

Even though I couldn't solve this helped by you, I wish I know where the problem may cause...

Thank you

Comment: You can try to save customer sessions in the database rather than the file system. Try changing the setting in app/etc/local.xml change the session save to db. Yes it's just the letters db.

Comment: @RussellAlbin Thank you for answering me, you mean that I have to change the extension local.xml to local.db, is it right that you mean?

Comment: First I apologize I am on my phone so I can't get you a code sample. In local.xml look at that file in your editor. Look for an XML node that is something like <session_save>files</session_save> and change that to <session_save>db</session_save> I may have the node name wrong but look for the word session and that's the one. This will help if your server is unable to read the session that are normally kept on the file system. I have seen that issue before and this seems to work. Check server logs for additional hints on your error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your store ist not assigned to a website,because getWebsite returns false

Comment: Hmm..? Actually, The project I have is already going on the remote website and working well.... except on my localhost... so do i have to change the setting somewhere?

Comment: It depends on many factors and how it is configured. First try to find out which store is used.

Comment: It could be that no store view is selected. Is the shop multistore ?

Comment: Yes, it is... but what you said inspires me that it could be wrong with database... What could I check this out?

Comment: What base_url do you have ? Do you have default store view ?

Answer (score 0):

> I think it's not about virtual host configuration, isn't it?

No. `getWebsite()` returns false, so your website/store configuration is broken. This can happen when you exported and imported a database with phpMyAdmin or a similar tool which automatically changes `0` values in increment_id columns if you don't configure it differently.

But Magento relies on a few ids to be always `0`.

#### The default website:

```
mysql> select website_id, code, name, sort_order, default_group_id, is_default from core_website;
+------------+-------+------------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
| website_id | code  | name                   | sort_order | default_group_id | is_default |
+------------+-------+------------------------+------------+------------------+------------+
|          0 | admin | Admin                  |          0 |                0 |          0 |
```

#### The NOT_LOGGED_IN customer group:

```
mysql> select customer_group_id, customer_group_code, tax_class_id from customer_group;
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------+
| customer_group_id | customer_group_code  | tax_class_id |
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------+
|                 0 | NOT LOGGED IN        |            3 |
```

Please make sure that these ids are correct, fix them in MySQL if necessary.